# How to calculate variance in python?

Tags: python, optimization, pyomo, portfolio

I'm trying to this:

```
   !pip install pyomo
    !wget -N -q "https://ampl.com/dl/open/ipopt/ipopt-linux64.zip"
    !unzip -o -q ipopt-linux64
    !apt-get install -y -qq glpk-utils
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import math
    from pyomo.environ import *
    from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
###########################################################################################

a='a'
assets=[str(a)+str(i) for i in range(1,60)]
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(36, 59)))
Cov=df.cov()
def get_covariance(Cov, i, j):
    return Cov[i][j]   
model=ConcreteModel()
model.i=Set(initialize=assets)
model.w=Var(model.i, within=NonNegativeReals)
w=model.w
model.v=Var(model.i, domain=Binary)
v=model.v
model.cov = Param(model.i, model.i, rule = get_covariance, doc = 'covariance')
cov=model.cov
model.objective = Objective(expr=sum((w[i]*w[j]*cov[i][j] for i in model.i) for j in model.i), sense=minimize)  
def Constraint1(model):
    return sum(w[i] for i in model.i)==1
model.Const1=Constraint( rule=Constraint1 )

#results
Solver=SolverFactory('ipopt',executable='/content/ipopt')
results=Solver.solve(model, tee=False)
```

My goal is to get the min variance

But unfortunately it does not work properly.
I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: what is your error and at which line? post (most important part of) traceback

Comment: Can you please run the code in colab @dankal444?